# Открытие страницы в новой вкладке

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-extension

Пытаюсь написать дополнение для Firefox, которое будет открывать группу вкладок.

При использовании window.open('url'), открывается новое окно. Как это обойти?
Между тем, если я вызываю window.open('url') в обычном скрипте, то страница открывается в новой вкладке. Это довольно странно. Может быть, есть способ явно указать браузеру на то, что открываться страница должна именно в новой вкладке?

Comment: это читали ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs

Comment: Уф, там надо еще что-то устанавливать :(
Спасибо за наводку.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы используете [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) для написания дополнения, то как верно замечено в комментах, это делается с помощью модуля tabs:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.open("http://www.example.com");
```

В обычном расширении (без SDK), [обычно используется](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Opening_a_URL_in_a_new_tab):

```
gBrowser.addTab(url)
```

Больше подробностей на странице по ссылке и тут: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code